# What is the convention when exporting point locations in a CSV?

Tags: export, csv

When creating a CVS export which includes a point location, what is the most popular convention to export the data?

I can imagine a few ways

| GEOJSON LON,LAT as string | "Lat,Lon" | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "LON,LAT" | "LAT,LON" | Lat | Lon |

Lat and Lon in separate cols seems safest, if perhaps a touch more work for the importer.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, this is either a survey Question, asking which form is most popular, or a discussion topic. Either way, there isn't any one right answer, so this is likely to be closed as *opinion-based*. I'd think that combining them is more work for the importer, because the X,Y vs. Lat,Lon order dichotomy is going to make more work for those who want them in a different order and those who want them separate.

Comment: You could also consider using WKT representation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

Comment: Unfortunately there are two interpretations about the right order of geographic coordinates in WKT: lon-lat or lat-lon.

Comment: @user30184 the section 7 of this OGC implementation standard seem to imply that the order is <x> <y> (and optionally <z> <m> ) so lon-lat (Wikipedia present WKT the same way as (x,y)). Did you have reference of WKT defined as lat-lon ?

Comment: @user30184 forgot the link in previous comment : https://www.ogc.org/standard/sfa/

Comment: Yes, MySQL in version 8.0 started to use lat-lon as default for geographic coordinates but it is not the only one. Since v. 8.0 MySQL requires using the option `axis-order long-lat` for reading WKT from software like PostGIS https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the info, that seem useful to know

Comment: Personally I would avoid CSV format altogether as its essentially a dumb text file. If you are allowed, I would export to something like dBase or geopackage as they are proper database tables that enforce data types/integrity. You've been warned...

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any ambiguity make sure that you use separate columns with clear column labels.